# Utilização de @SupressWarnings no Java

Tags: java, annotation

Bom dia.

Até quando é recomendável utilizar a anotação `@SuppressWarnings` para esconder uma *warning* de um determinado problema que o compilador encontra em seu código e mostrar que você sabe o que está fazendo? Faço isso para não poluir os packages e as classes com o alerta amarelo utilizando o Eclipse.

O que recomendam e o que tem a dizer sobre isso? Existem outras opções de esconder um *warning*? Quais são?

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: A melhor opção é não esconder o warning mas sim eliminar a sua causa. Não me lembro a última vez que usei um *@SuppressWarnings*... O que eu faço é ler o motivo do warning e corrigir o problema.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Regras gerais de como lidar com *warnings*

Obviamente, a finalidade do `@SuppressWarnings` é fazer o compilador não emitir *warnings*. Entretanto utilizá-lo de forma adequada requer bom-senso. Eis algumas regras de como usá-lo de forma adequada:

- Ao se deparar com uma *warning* em particular, tente entender o que a causa primeiro. Não saia colocando `@SuppressWarnings` de qualquer jeito em qualquer coisa!
- Tente eliminar as *warnings* ao alterar-se o código para fazê-la sumir, ou seja corrija o problema que a *warning*  está dizendo que você tem. Veja mais abaixo aqui na minha resposta como lidar com os casos mais comuns.
- Se não puder eliminar uma *warning* em particular, pense se realmente você quer suprimi-la. Às vezes deixar o compilador ficar gritando insistentemente cada vez que você compila o código é melhor do que silenciá-lo, pois no futuro, se/quando alguém/você tiver uma solução para a *warning* ela não ficará esquecida. Além disso, a *warning* sempre serve como um lembrete que há alguns débitos técnicos pendentes de resolução.
- Se você realmente quiser silenciar a *warning*, coloque o `@SuppressWarnings` no menor escopo possível. Ou seja, se você puder colocá-la em uma variável local ao invés de colocar no método todo, prefira colocar na variável local.
- Se você colocar um `@SuppressWarnings` no seu código, é bom colocar um comentário (com `// ...` ou `/* ... */`) explicando o porquê de você estar suprimindo uma *warning* em particular, a menos que seja um caso muito óbvio.
- Se você for fazer alterações em algum código que use o `@SuppressWarnings`, veja isso como uma oportunidade em potencial de remover o `@SuppressWarnings`. Sempre dê uma olhada se ao alterar o código, você não acaba por eliminar/corrigir a stituação que gera a *warning*, e portanto não mais precisando suprimi-la.

E os casos mais comuns onde as *warnings* podem ser eliminadas são:

## 1. *Warning* `unchecked`

Este é o caso mais comum, e frequentemente pode acontecer quando os tipos genéricos não coincidem, mas mesmo assim você pode assegurar-se de que o programa funciona.

A warning *unchecked* é disparada mais frequentemente em *casts*. Em geral *casts* são verificados em tempo de execução, mas com os tipos genéricos, devido ao *type-erasure*, a verificação do tipo genérico não é efetuada em tempo de execução, ficando esta restrita apenas ao tipo base. Por exemplo:

```java
public List<?> devolveAlgumaLista() {
    if (condicaoQualquer) {
        return new ArrayList<Gato>();
    } else {
        return new ArrayList<Cachorro>();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void metodoQualquer() {
    List<?> lista = devolveAlgumaLista();

    if (outraCondicao) {
        for (Cachorro c : (List<Cachorro>) lista) { // Cast unchecked.
             System.out.println(c.latir());
        }
    } else {
        for (Gato g : (List<Gato>) lista) { // Cast unchecked.
             System.out.println(g.miar());
        }
    }
}
```

Outro exemplo:

```java
public List metodoBemAntigoEmAlgumaBiblioteca() {
    // ...
}

public void meuMetodoNovo() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Abacaxi> lista = (List<Abacaxi>) metodoBemAntigoEmAlgumaBiblioteca();
}
```

Um outro lugar aonde ela pode ocorrer é em arrays genéricos:

```java
public <T> void metodo() {
    T[] array = ...; // warning unchecked
}
```

E isso ocorre porque o tipo do genérico é perdido por causa do *type-erasure*, o que permite eu inserir no array elementos que violam as restrições de tipo que o compilador impõe (o que é denominado de *heap pollution*). O *heap pollution*  também pode acontecer com listas, mapas e outras estruturas de dados quando as regras dos generics são violadas. Quando a sua aplicação sofre com *heap pollution*, o resultado mais comum é você ter `ClassCastException`s sendo lançadas em lugares inesperados.

Ter retorno de métodos, parâmetros ou variáveis cujos tipos dependem de circunstâncias que não podem ser verificadas pelo compilador em geral não é uma boa ideia, e o ideal é que o código seja reestruturado de forma a garantir que o compilador tenha como fazer a verificação de tipos adequadamente. Arrays genéricos raramente são boa ideia também. Entretanto, de vez em quando esta situação acontece de uma forma da qual não é possível se evitar, e é por isso que temos o `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

Para eliminar esta *warning*, o ideal é:

- **Estudar** muito bem os *generics* e aprender a utilizá-los também para criar classes genéricas, incluindo como usar os tipos coringas (tais como `List<? super Foo>`). Muitos dos lugares aonde a *warning unchecked* aparece é resultado de código desenvolvido por pessoas que não sabem como utilizar adequadamente os *generics*.
- **Entender** o que é *heap pollution*, pois é exatamente contra isso que a *warning unchecked* tenta alertar.
- Não utilizar tipos brutos (tais como `List` e `Map` ao invés de `List<Foo>` e `Map<Foo, Bar>`). Sempre procure declarar todos os tipos genéricos necessários, mesmo que alguns deles sejam tipos coringas (com `<?>`) ou sejam variáveis de tipos.
- Utilizar os métodos `java.util.Collections.checked*` em coleções e mapas aonde os tipos genéricos sejam simples, tal como `java.util.Collections.checkedList(lista, String.class)`.
- Evitar misturar arrays com tipos genéricos. O melhor é trabalhar com listas ou com algum outro tipo de estrutura de dados, ainda mais que arrays são uma estrutura de dado de baixo nível e idealmente devem ser abstraídos se possível. O método `java.util.Arrays.asList(T... a)` é muito útil nessas circustâncias.
- Evitar declarar parâmetros do tipo `Object` e retornos do tipo `Object`. Quando isso acontecer, pode ser que utilizar um tipo genérico seria melhor do que utilizar `Object`.
- Utilizar os métodos `java.lang.Class.cast(Class<U> c)` e `java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class<S> c)`. Com estes métodos é possível implementar-se *casts* dinâmicos em tempo de execução.
- Não fazer *casts* para variáveis de tipos (tais como `return (T) obj;`). Se possível, use o objeto `Class` adequado para isso (como em `return classT.cast(obj);`).
- Declarar parâmetros com um tipo genérico `Class<X>`, aonde `X` é uma variável de tipo declarada no método em questão.
- Evitar ao máximo criar estruturas de dados heterogêneas (ou seja, que podem conter mais do que um tipo de objeto, tal como uma lista que contenha uma mistura de gatos e cachorros).
- Se você realmente precisar misturar arrays com tipos genéricos ao invés de usar um `List` ou um `Map`, tenha certeza que você sabe muito bem o que está fazendo.

E é claro, se nenhuma das alternativas for possível, então a solução seria usar o `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

## 2. *Warning* `rawtypes`

Semelhante ao `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`, este daqui acontece quando tipos brutos são declarados. Tipos brutos são aqueles tipos deveriam ser genéricos, mas em que os genéricos não foram utilizados, tipicamente decorrente do uso de classes legadas anteriores ao Java 5.

Por exemplo:

```
public void meuMetodo() {
    List elementos = ...; // warning rawtypes
    // ...
}
```

A solução para as *warnings* deste tipo são as mesmas que se aplicam à *unchecked*, apenas a situação específica na qual ela ocorre é um pouco diferente. E obviamente, existem casos aonde ela não pode ser eliminada, e portanto o `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")` poderá ser usado.

## 3. *Warning* `deprecation`

Esta daqui acontece quando você utiliza um método *deprecated* ou sobreescreve um método *deprecated*. Por exemplo:

```
 public void fazerAlgo() {
     JPasswordField jf = // ...
     String x = jf.getText(); // warning deprecation
     // ...
 }
```

Para eliminar esta *warning*, o ideal é:

- Não usar o método, atributo ou classe *deprecated*, afinal se foi marcado como *deprecated* é porque há algum motivo para não ser usado. E quando isso acontece, geralmente existe alguma outra coisa que deveria ser usada no lugar.
- Se o método ou a classe que você está implementando/codificando/alterando também está *deprecated*, então marque o método (ou talvez até a classe inteira) com `@Deprecated`.

## 4. *Warning* `dep-ann`

Se o método, classe, campo ou construtor que você está implementando/codificando/alterando tiver um javadoc com uma tag `@deprecated`, mas sem a anotação `@Deprecated`, você vai receber uma *warning dep-ann*. Para corrigi-la basta acrescentar a anotação `@Deprecated`.

Em geral, não há sentido em ignorar-se a *warning dep-ann*, ainda mais que corrigi-la é fácil. A única situação aonde não se pode corrigi-la é em código que deve manter compatibilidade com versões do java anteriores a 5 e que portanto não podem ter anotações. Mas neste caso, você também não poderá suprimir a *warning* com o `@SuppressWarnings`.

## 5. *Warning* `hiding`

É o que acontece quando são declaradas duas variáveis com o mesmo nome, mas ambas presentes no mesmo escopo, tal como no código abaixo:

```
public class MinhaClasse {
    private int x;

    public void metodo() {
        int x = 25; // warning hiding
        // ...
    }
}
```

Ter duas variáveis com mesmo nome visíveis em um mesmo escopo é uma má prática de programação (apenas *setters* em geral são perdoados, mas há quem discorde disso, inclusive eu).

Para corrigir esta *warning*, o ideal é renomear uma das variáveis que está colidindo. E é mais fácil renomear-se a que tem o menor escopo. No caso de variáveis locais, não há motivo para esta correção não ser feita. É raro uma correção não ser possível, tal como no caso da classe interna ter um atributo público com o mesmo nome de um atributo público na classe externa. E em geral, quando algum caso mais complexo de *hiding* acontece, é sinal de que você tem problemas bem maiores no seu código. Mas se você não puder corrigir, então use o `@SuppressWarnings("hiding")`.

## 6. *Warning* `unused`

Ocorre quando você tem métodos, campos, construtores ou classes internas (em geral privados) que não são utilizados. Também pode ocorrer com parâmetros e variáveis locais que não são utilizados.

- No caso de variáveis locais, não há desculpa para mantê-las, o melhor é apenas eliminá-las.
- No caso de campos, métodos, construtores e classes internas privadas que parecem não ser utilizadas, o ideal é apenas eliminá-los.
- No caso de parâmetros, exceto no caso de *overriding* ou de parâmetros que devem permanecer para garantir compatibilidade, o ideal é eliminá-los.
- Nos casos aonde um campo, construtor, método ou classe interna privada e aparentemente nunca usada puder ser acessada por meio de *reflection*, neste caso é válido usar `@SuppressWarnings("unused")`.

## 7. *Warning* `varargs`

Você declarou um parâmetro que é um array vararg de um tipo genérico, o que pode te trazer problemas de *heap pollution* (veja no item do *unchecked*). Em geral a solução para isso é tentar usar um `List` ou um `Map` ao invés do array, ou usar o `java.util.Arrays.asList(T...)`. Também vale dar uma olhada na anotação `@SafeVarargs`. Apenas se nenhuma destas opções for válidas, é que o `@SuppressWarnings("varargs")` deve ser considerado.

## 8. *Warning* `fallthrough`

O `switch` já é uma construção de linguagem horrorosa que o Java herdou do C. Pior ainda é ter herdado o *fallthrough*. Na maioria dos casos aonde isso ocorre, é porque você esqueceu um `break` (ou talvez um `throw` ou `return`) no seu `switch`, e neste caso o que você tem que fazer é corrigir o erro.

Mesmo quando o *fallthrough* é intencional, utilizá-lo em geral é uma má prática de programação, e você deveria codificar o seu `switch` de forma a não precisar do *fallthrough*, ou até mesmo de forma a não precisar do `switch`. Uma forma de não precisar do `switch` é tentar transformar cada `case` em uma sobreescrita de um método polimórfico abstrato e invocá-lo ao invés de fazer o `switch`. A partir do Java 8, possível encontrar-se formas de substituir por algumas *lambdas expressions*, embora isso seja um tanto difícil no caso do *fallthrough*.

Mas, se o *fallthrough* for realmente necessário e você não puder eliminá-lo (ou a menos, não facilmente), então coloque o `@SuppressWarnings("fallthrough")`.

## 9. *Warning* `restriction`

Você está utilizando alguma classe que não faz parte da API pública e não deveria ser utilizada diretamente, tais como aquelas nos pacotes `sun.*`. E a melhor solução é simplesmente não utilizar esta classe e sim utilizar alguma alternativa que não esteja em um pacote proibido. Se você está tentando decidir em tempo de execução se ela será usada, ou se uma alternativa será procurada, o ideal é acessá-la apenas via *reflection*.

Entretanto, se você não tiver outra escolha que não seja usar a tal classe e não quiser apenas deixar o compilador reclamando sempre, então o jeito é usar o `@SuppressWarnings("restriction")`.

## 10. *Warning* `serial`

Você definiu uma classe serializável que não tem o `serialVersionUID`. Uma classe serializável é uma que implementa a interface `java.io.Serializable`, mesmo que indiretamente (ou seja, implementa uma interface que herda de `java.io.Serializable` ou então herda de uma classe que implementa `java.io.Serializable`).

Nos casos aonde você não se importa com a serialização, é seguro suprimir esta *warning*. Porém é melhor se ao invés disso, você apenas declarar o campo `serialVersionUID` adequadamente.

## 11. *Warning* `cast`

Você está utilizando um *cast* desnecessário no código (tal como fazer `String x = (String) "Hello World";`). Neste caso o ideal é simplesmente remover o *cast*. É difícil se imaginar um caso aonde este *warning* deva ser suprimido ao invés de apenas corrigido.

## 12. Outras *warnings*

Existem muitas outras *warnings*. Veja estes links:

- [*Warnings* do javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#BHCJBHDF)
- [*Warnings* do Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1206001/540552)
- [*Warnings* do Netbeans](https://jazzy.id.au/2008/10/30/list_of_suppresswarnings_arguments.html) <sup><sub>(desatualizado, sinta-se livre para editar se achar uma referência melhor)</sub></sup>
- Outras ferramentas, tais como o [***Checkstyle***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkstyle), o [***FindBugs***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FindBugs) e o [***Checker Framework***](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/) também têm as suas warnings específicas.

Para estas *warnings* mais específicas, verifique a documentação relevante para entender o que está acontecendo, e como eliminar o problema ou então e se é pertinente ou não usar `@SuppressWarnings`.

Muitas dessas *warnings* são simples de se corrigir e não tem sentido em serem ignoradas, tais como `empty`, `dep-ann` e `cast`. Outras podem ser apenas chatice do compilador, e neste caso, se não puderem ser corrigidas, o melhor é ignorá-las, tais como `unqualified-field-access`, `serial` e `processing`. Entretanto, há sempre algumas que são importantes e podem ser difíceis de se arrumar, tais como `unchecked`, `finally` e `fallthrough`. Mas lembre-se, sempre tente primeiramente corrigir a *warning*, e só se você não puder corrigir e nem achar melhor deixar o compilador continuar a reclamar, é que pense em silenciá-la com o `@SuppressWarnings`.

## 13. `@SuppressWarnings("all")`

Usar o `@SuppressWarnings("all")` é o último recurso, pois silencia todas as *warnings*. Idealmente você não deveria utilizar `@SuppressWarnings("all")` nunca, mas há dois casos que me vem a mente em que isso faz sentido:

- A classe é gerada e regerada automaticamente por alguma ferramenta antes ou durante o processo de compilação, e por causa disso, não é desejável que o compilador fique reclamando de *warnings* nela.
- A classe foi copiada e colada de algum outro lugar ou foi recebida de algum outro lugar e por algum motivo ela não deve sofrer nenhuma alteração (que não seja a alteração de adicionar o próprio `@SuppressWarnings`). Neste caso, é melhor silenciar todas as *warnings* que o compilador for emitir acerca desta classe.

Comment: Muito boa a resposta +1